# Order by table column in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I'm tearing my hair out with this one; I've got a series of records I need to get out of the database to build an array. `positive_votes` is a column of integer values on each `opinion`, so naturally I want to only get the five `Opinion` records with the highest integer values and return them in order, from the highest (top value) to the fifth highest. From reading the Rails Guides, I came up with this query:

```
@opinions = Opinion.order(positive_votes: :desc).limit(5)
```

Unfortunately, it's not working. What it appears to be doing is returning the first record created chronologically, then the four next ones. It's been a long day, so I'm fully prepared for this to be a dumb mistake, but any help would be really appreciated.

EDIT:

The SQL generated is as follows,

```
(0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(count_column) FROM (SELECT 1 AS count_column FROM "opinions" LIMIT 5) subquery_for_count 
  Opinion Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "opinions".* FROM "opinions" ORDER BY '---
:postive_votes: :desc' LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Does the log print out the raw SQL that generates?

Comment: Yeah - will update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can use `order` with symbols.  Try the following:

```
@opinions = Opinion.order('positive_votes desc').limit(5)
```

Comment: That would explain the `.to_s` barf in the SELECT statement: `'---
:postive_votes: :desc'`

Comment: Worked, nice one. For some reason I was convinced that you had to use symbols with the `.order` method.